# Grails criteria projections - get rows count

Tags: java, hibernate, grails

I have Hotel entity:

```
class Hotel {
City city
}
```

Now, i need count of hotels with given city.
It could be done in this way:

```
def hotels = Hotel.findAllByCity(city)
def cnt = hotels.size()
```

But it's very **dirty** way. It seems that with criteria it would be better, but i have no idea how to implement it...

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There are dynamic counters as well as finders on domain objects:

```
Hotel.countByCity(city)
```

More details in the [user guide](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/countBy.html), of course

Answer (score 49):

[Dave is right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2327743/grails-criteria-projections-get-rows-count/2327768#2327768) that you can use the [countBy*](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/countBy.html) methods for simple counting.  If you need more than two criteria you will have to revert to the [criteria api](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/5.%20Object%20Relational%20Mapping%20(GORM).html#5.4.2%20Criteria), [HQL](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/5.%20Object%20Relational%20Mapping%20(GORM).html#5.4.3%20Hibernate%20Query%20Language%20%28HQL%29) or SQL.  It is very common to need more than two criteria especially with an active and evolving codebase.

Here is an example of how you would use the [Criteria api](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/5.%20Object%20Relational%20Mapping%20(GORM).html#5.4.2%20Criteria) to do [projections](https://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/v3/api/org/hibernate/criterion/Projections.html):

```
def c = Hotel.createCriteria()

def hotelCount = c.get {
    projections {
        count('id')
    }
    gt("stars", 2)          
    eq("city", city)            
    eq("deleted", false)

}
```

Alternatively (more elegantly) you could even use Criteria#count like the following:

```
def c = Hotel.createCriteria()

def hotelCount = c.count {
    gt("stars", 2)          
    eq("city", city)            
    eq("deleted", false)

}
```

Just for completeness sake:

```
class Hotel {
    City city
    Boolean deleted = false
    Integer stars
}

class City {
    String name
}
```

An integration test (using the [build-test-data plugin](http://www.grails.org/plugin/build-test-data))

```
import grails.test.*

class HotelTests extends GrailsUnitTestCase {

    void testCriteria() {
        City city1 = City.build(name:'one')
        assertNotNull(city1)
        City city2 = City.build(name:'two')
        assertNotNull(city1)

        Hotel fiveStarHotel= Hotel.build(city:city1, deleted:false, stars:5)
        assertNotNull(fiveStarHotel)

        Hotel hotelInCity2 = Hotel.build(city:city2, deleted:false, stars:5)
        assertNotNull(hotelInCity2)

        Hotel deletedHotel = Hotel.build(city:city1, deleted:true, stars:5)
        assertNotNull(deletedHotel)

        Hotel threeStarHotel = Hotel.build(city:city1, deleted:false, stars:3)
        assertNotNull(threeStarHotel)

        Hotel oneStarHotel = Hotel.build(city:city1, deleted:false, stars:1)
        assertNotNull(oneStarHotel)

        def c = Hotel.createCriteria()

        def hotelCount = c.get {
            projections {
                count('id')
            }
            gt("stars", 2)          
            eq("city", city1)           
            eq("deleted", false)

        }
        assertEquals(2, hotelCount) //should only find the 5 and 3 star hotel

        def c2 = Hotel.createCriteria()
        hotelCount = c2.count {
            gt("stars", 2)          
            eq("city", city1)           
            eq("deleted", false)

        }
        assertEquals(2, hotelCount) //should only find the 5 and 3 star hotel
    }
}
```

Comment: just for simplicity, how can I put the criteria into one line? should I add semicolon (;) for each statement?

Comment: I believe you can do: Hotel.createCriteria().count { gt("stars", 2); eq("city", city); eq("deleted", false) } but I haven't tried it yet.

Comment: What if I wanted to figure out what cities had more than one hotel?

Comment: Looks like the "having" clause is not supported in GORM criteria queries, but is in HQL.