# Grails projections group by and count

Tags: grails, group-by, projection

Following are my two classes

```
class Users {
    String emailAddress
    String password
    //    String filename
    String firstName
    String lastName
    Date dateCreated
    Date lastUpdated
}
```

and

```
class SharedDocuments {
    Users author
    Users receiver
    Documents file
    static constraints = {

    }
}
```

I want to run a query similar to this one, essentially i want to get list of all the users along with count of documents they have authored

```
SELECT author_id, COUNT(SharedDocuments.id )FROM SharedDocuments 
  INNER JOIN users ON author_id = users.id
  GROUP BY author_id
```

This is what I have so far

```
def sharedDocumentsInstanceList = SharedDocuments.createCriteria().list(params){
    createAlias("author","a")
    eq("receiver.id",session.uid)  
    projections{
        groupProperty "author"
        count "id",'mycount'

    }
     order('mycount','desc')
    maxResults(params.max)
}
```

I have this 90% working, if i get rid of `count` or `countDistinct` I get list of distinct authors but what i want is authors along with the counts of documents. So when i add the count or countDistinct clause to this criteria I just get array of long!!
like [2,3,4] what I want is [[author1,2],[author2,3] ...]
How can i achive this I have already seen [Grails: Projection on many tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5771627/grails-projection-on-many-tables),
[Grails criteria projections - get rows count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2327743/grails-criteria-projections-get-rows-count), 
[Grails groupProperty and order. How it works?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5220450/grails-groupproperty-and-order-how-it-works),
but none of the answers seem to be solving my issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Projections with pagination has a bug where it only return the last field in the projections block. The current grails 2.1.5 has this bug fixed. Here is the reported bug http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-9644

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just use countBy* - like

```
    SharedDocuments.countByAuthorAndReceiver(user, receiver)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the result as as you described in your query then you need the id of the author or any other specific property like email.

```
def sharedDocumentsInstanceList = SharedDocuments.createCriteria().list(params){
    eq("receiver.id",session.uid)  
    projections{
        groupProperty "author"
        count "id",'mycount'

    }
     order('mycount','desc')
    maxResults(params.max)
}
```

Comment: no matter what I do my result set just has count no other information. Printing sharedDocumentsInstanceList in the code you have given me produces '[2, ]' output

Comment: I'm doing somewhat exactly the same thing but with a named query and without maxResults it works fine for me :(. BTW I'm not even doing author.id just grouping on author should work too